# MimeMultipart count is zero when an email is read using JavaMail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, mime-types, multipart

My application sends an email to an Exchange mail server, mail server is configured with a third party application where it routes email to agent and agent replies to that email. Application reads agent reply from the mailbox which is used to send the email.

Email sending code is below;

```
Message mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
                 mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                 mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                 mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
                 mimeMessage.setContent(emailText,"text/plain");

                 mimeMessage.setReplyTo(replyToAddress);

                 Transport.send(mimeMessage);
```

This works perfectly. When agent reply is received, Application read it as;

```
 if (message.isMimeType("multipart/MIXED")) {
                logger.info("Email MIME Type is: multipart/MIXED");
                MimeMultipart multipart =(MimeMultipart)message.getContent();

                logger.info("Content type = "+multipart.getContentType());
                int count = multipart.getCount();
}
```

The content type is "multipart/mixed" but the count is 0 means there are no parts in this emails.

I need to set System property,

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.multipart.allowempty", "true");
```

if it is not set, `multipart.getCount()` throws "missingBoundryException".

Why it is so ?
I can see that the agent's reply is not empty.
The email was sent with content type as text/plain, why reply type is multipart/mixed?

Is this due to any invalid formatting of email by third party application, what is the workaround?

Below is the snap of agent reply.
[image: Agent reply]

Below is the raw MIME content,

```
Received: from sociaminer.host (192.168.1.29) by thirdpartHost
 (192.168.1.53) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.1.218.12; Thu, 19 Jan
 2017 17:06:26 +0500
To: hafiz <hafiz@bla.bla>
Message-ID: <hassan.MESSAGEID@bla.bla>
In-Reply-To: <CF72F94@bla.bla>
References: <CF72F945A@bla.bla>
Subject: Re: 1122+50
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_127_14151461.1484827604583"
From: <reply@bla.bla>
Return-Path: reply@bla.bla
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 17:06:26 +0500
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: bla.bla
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 06
X-Originating-IP: [SocialMinerIP]
MIME-Version: 1.0

------=_Part_127_14151461.1484827604583
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">Reply to 50<br>

<blockquote><hr>
<b>From:</b> hafiz &lt;hafiz@bla.bla&gt;<br><b>Sent:</b> Thursday, January 19, 2017 5:05 PM<br><b>To:</b> testing2 &lt;testing2@bla.bla&gt;<br><b>Subject:</b> 1122&#43;50<br>

<html dir="ltr">
<head>

<style type="text/css" id="owaParaStyle"></style>
</head>
<body fpstyle="1" ocsi="0">
<div style="direction: ltr;font-family: Tahoma;color: #000000;font-size: 10pt;">Testing 50</div>
</body>
</html>
</blockquote>
------=_Part_127_14151461.1484827604583--
```

JavaMail debug output looks like below,

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: disable AUTH=PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "Echange IP", port 143, isSSL false
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=192.168.1.53, user=hafiz@bla.bla, password=<non-null>
A1 STARTTLS
A1 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE NTLM command trace suppressed
DEBUG NTLM: type 1 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 01 00 00 00 03 A2 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 03 00 03 00 20 00 00 00 31 39 32 
DEBUG NTLM: type 3 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 03 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 68 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 22 00 22 00 40 00 00 00 06 00 06 00 62 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 98 00 00 00 01 82 00 00 68 00 61 00 66 00 69 00 7A 00 40 00 65 00 66 00 6C 00 61 00 62 00 2E 00 6C 00 6F 00 63 00 61 00 6C 00 31 00 39 00 32 00 3B 5E 2B 86 67 49 E3 01 C9 9E F2 CA ED 54 21 11 81 89 94 C6 EC E0 26 E3 BA DB E7 5A F4 CA 28 17 7C 0E 8A 08 18 B5 5A 4E 72 4F C5 7F 52 64 FA 76 
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE NTLM command result: A3 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A4 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A4 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
A5 SELECT INBOX
* 40 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 39] Is the first unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 436] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 46] The next unique identifier value
A5 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
A6 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH 39
A6 OK SEARCH completed.
A7 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH 39
A7 OK SEARCH completed.
main INFO  emailToSms.EmailReader - 1 unread emails read from inbox.
A8 STORE 39 +FLAGS (\Seen)
* 39 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
A8 OK STORE completed.
A9 FETCH 39 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER])
* 39 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {851}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from HOST (IP) by HOST
 (192.168.1.53) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.1.218.12; Thu, 19 Jan
 2017 17:06:26 +0500
To: hafiz <hafiz@bla.bla>
Message-ID: <hassan.B69E3DD110000159000004A73F57FEE3.1484827604448.cisco-ccp@bla.bla>
In-Reply-To: <CF72F945A1ED2E438A53A11DA9415F65A0E981@Expert.bla.bla>
References: <CF72F945A1ED2E438A53A11DA9415F65A0E981@Expert.bla.bla>
Subject: Re: 1122+50
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_127_14151461.1484827604583"
From: <testing2@bla.bla>
Return-Path: testing2@bla.bla
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 17:06:26 +0500
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: Expert.bla.bla
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 06
X-Originating-IP: [IP]

)
A9 OK FETCH completed.
A10 FETCH 39 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* 39 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Thu, 19 Jan 2017 17:06:26 +0500" "Re: 1122+50" ((NIL NIL "testing2" "bla.bla")) NIL NIL (("hafiz" NIL "hafiz" "bla.bla")) NIL NIL "<CF72F945A1ED2E438A53A11DA9415F65A0E981@Expert.bla.bla>" "<hassan.B69E3DD110000159000004A73F57FEE3.1484827604448.cisco-ccp@bla.bla>") INTERNALDATE "19-Jan-2017 17:06:26 +0500" RFC822.SIZE 1250)
A10 OK FETCH completed.
A11 FETCH 39 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 39 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ("multipart" "mixed" ("boundary" "----=_Part_127_14151461.1484827604583") NIL NIL 7BIT 0 NIL NIL NIL NIL))
A11 OK FETCH completed.

DEBUG IMAP: IMAPProtocol noop
A12 NOOP
A12 OK NOOP completed.
```

Comment: Post the raw MIME content of the reply so we can see what's wrong with it.  You can get it by using message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); and then look at the msg.txt.file.

Comment: @BillShannon raw MIME content added.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Are you using IMAP?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Yes, I am using IMAP. Debug output added.

Comment: DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "ExchangeIP", port 143, isSSL false. SSL is false, is this okay ?

Comment: Yes, SSL is false because you're using STARTTLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Microsoft Exchange.  Report this bug to Microsoft and upgrade to a newer version or newer service pack if possible in case they've already fixed it.

Exchange is returning the BODYSTRUCTURE information for the message as if it were a single part message when in fact it is a multipart message.  This is a violation of the IMAP protocol spec.

You can use the [workaround in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#imapserverbug).

Also, you  might want to [upgrade to a newer version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) - 1.4.7 is pretty old, the current version is 1.5.6.

Comment: Same issue with JavaMail 1.5.6 as well.
Upgrading Exchange worked. Thanks.